# how to treeview appendnode speed up with devexpress

Tags: c#, treeview, devexpress, nodes

my linux filesystem management program.

file count : 170,000

```
/*filelist load*/
treelist.beginUpdate();
treelist.beginUnboundLoad();
foreach(datarow dr_file in dt_filesystem)
{
treelist.AppendNode(new object[]{ /*file info*/ , parentNode}
}
treelist.endUnboudLoad();
treelist.endUpdate();
```

treenode AppendNode so slow. how to fast treeview appendNode?

filecount 1000 : 2sec

but filecount 170,000 : 10hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load all data at once and improve TreeList initialization, put all your objects in a list and bind your TreeList to this list. For example:

```
var dataSource = new BindingList<TreeListItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 170000; i++)
{
    dataSource.Add(new TreeListItem() { ID = i, ParentID = i % 3 });
}
treeList1.DataSource = dataSource;
```

---

```
public class TreeListItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Virtual Mode (Dynamic Data Loading)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5560/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List/Feature-Center/Data-Binding/Virtual-Mode-Dynamic-Data-Loading-Using-Events) to load required data on demand.